# React container with render logic?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a container, which renders 3 components:
1. list of items
2. new item modal
3. edit item modal

In order to control the whole container functions, I need to call the list of items with column list. Is it ok that all will be inside the container?
Is it ok to render modal within the container? (The modal contains the 2 and 3 components)

```
class Items extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            modal: false
        }

        this.columns = [
            ...
        ]

        this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this)
    }

    openModal(type, item) {
        this.setState({
            modal: {
                type,
                item: item && item.toJS()
            }
        })
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.setState({modal: false})
    }

    renderModal() {
        const {item, type} = this.state.modal;

        return (
            <Modal onClose={this.closeModal}>
                {type == modalTypes.NEW_ITEM &&
                <ItemForm onCancel={this.closeModal}
                              onSubmit={...}/>}
                {type == modalTypes.REMOVE_ITEM &&
                <ConfirmationDialog text="Are you sure you want to remove?"
                                    onSubmit={...} onCancel={this.closeModal}/>}
                {type == modalTypes.EDIT_ITEM &&
                <ItemForm onCancel={this.closeModal}
                              onSubmit={...}/>}
            </Modal>
        )
    }

    render() {
        const {visibleItems, display_type} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="_header_container">
                    <Header title="Items"/>
                    <div className="actions">
                        <Search />
                        <DisplayToggle />
                        <Button size="sm" color="primary"
                                onClick={() => ...}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {display_type == displayType.GRID &&
                <Grid items={visibleItems} columns={this.columns}/>}
                {display_type == displayType.TILE &&
                <TileView items={visibleItems} titleKey="name" linkKey="url"/>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        remove: (item) => dispatch(remove(item)),
        edit: (item, ...) => dispatch(edit(item, ...)),
        create: (name, val) => dispatch(create(name, url)),
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        visibleItems: filterItems(state.items, state.search),
        display_type: state.display_type
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Items)
```

Thanks

Comment: You should generally show code when posting a question.

Comment: If you post some example code with comments in the areas you have questions it will help people understand your problem better (to whoever down voted the question: maybe wait a litte bit to see if he responds to these comments and improves on his question)

Comment: Sure. I just edited

Comment: I believe the cleaner approach is to abstract the modal into it's own component. Then just pass the click handlers, open status, etc. to the component. That would reduce the amount of code in this container component (specifically the renderModal function). This would also make the modal reusable in other components.

Comment: And what about the columns? Should I leave it like that inside the container?

Comment: @AlexK can you please explain me how to call the modal? Do I have to save the modal in a state?